# Positive definite function on the upper half line and its integral expression

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

By Hausdorff-Bernstein-Widder theorem, any completely monotonic function on the half line $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}:=[0,\infty)$
is given by the Laplace transform of a positive measure on $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$, but how about positive definite function?

Is every positive definite function on $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$
of the form
$f(x)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-tx}\,d\mu(t)$ for some positive measure on $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$?

Here a continuous function $f(x)$ on $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ is called positive definite if $\sum_{k,l}^Na_k\overline{a_l}f(x_k+x_l)\geq 0$ is satisfied for all $a_1,\cdots,a_N\in\mathbb{C}$ and $x_1,\cdots,x_N\in\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$.

Comment: you have Bochner's theorem at least http://www.math.iit.edu/~fass/603_ch2.pdf. Also check out Theorem 2.4.2 and Theorem 2.5.3 if you also have radial.

Comment: Thank you for your referece, but the definition of positive definiteness I adopt differs from the one.

Comment: It is not $f(x_k-x_l)$ but $f(x_k+x_l)$.

Comment: So I am taking a look whether you can at least get Bochner back. I am looking at the Folland proof typed here too online http://individual.utoronto.ca/jordanbell/notes/bochnertheorem.pdf. It seems to me that you still get  Theorem 3 because I think you can just skip the very last inequality and you get nonnegative where he has $\phi(x+y)$.

Comment: This nonnegative is crucial to Hermitian inner product.

Comment: To get the form you particularly mentioned, it would seem that you also need radial, which in 1d you get for free. So a suggestion is to try to mimic the proofs that positive-def+radial = completely monotone for your particular class of functions with x+y instead.